# Condensing for loop expressions (Python)

Tags: python, loops, syntax, obfuscation

Is there a way to condense this pair of loops down to two or one lines?:

```
for x in y:
         z = 1
        while x > z: z += 1
```

to look more like (aware the below doesn't work):

```
for x in y: z = 1
    while x > z: z += 1
```

Please note: the point isn't to resolve the actual loops, just that the `for` loop must contain a counter variable of some kind prior to the while loop.

The question is purely about the syntax, so resolving z's value is not the query here.  the code could be this instead:

```
for x in y:
      z = 1 
      q = 0
      while z < x:
            q += 1
```

Or any other combination of a for and while loop where there is at least one variable defined between the `for` and `while`, but I want the loops condensed, not to remove the use of the loops entirely.

Comment: Using a comprehension is usually the way to condense loops like this, but you'd need to provide an example that's a little more real-world (where you're actually building a list) to get a good example of how to translate it into a comprehension.  The answer to this one is just `z = y[-1]`.  :P

Comment: @Samwise I have edited the main post to try to better reflect the question; the goal isn't to resolve the value of z, that's just an example for the syntax. It's for any pair of a `for` and `while` loop where there is at least one variable declared inside the scope of the `for` and before the `while`.

Comment: Why do you have a loop with a scalar variable that's constantly being re-initialized?  Why not just do the last iteration of the loop?  Again: normally the point of such a loop is to build a list, in which case you'd do a comprehension, but it's not possible to demonstrate that with the example you've provided.

Comment: the function of the code is not relevant, this is purely a question about syntax. Please disregard the actual result of the code; the question is only whether there is a way to write the same code, with the same values, and the same two loops, just on fewer lines. Without actually changing the code.

For example, i can have `while z < x: q += 1` all on one line. The q+= 1 doesn't need to be below the while loop, but by convention it is. So the question is if there is a way to condense this little snippet of code down any smaller, without changing the actual components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe this?

```py
for x, z in [(x, 1) for x in y]:
    while x > z:
        z += 1
```